# Populating JTable with Vector?

Tags: java, swing

I am getting the following error when I try to populate a `JTable` using vectors.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(DefaultTableModel.java:268)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:159)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync$Model.<init>(Package_sync.java:50)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync.packageTable(Package_sync.java:43)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync.<init>(Package_sync.java:16)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync$2.run(Package_sync.java:116)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code:

```
private void packageTable() {
    Vector tableHeadings = new Vector();
    tableHeadings.add("PACKAGE NAMES");
    tableHeadings.add("SHOW");
    Table1.setModel(new Model(fileVector, tableHeadings));
}

class Model extends DefaultTableModel {
    Vector heading = null;
    Model(Vector data, Vector heading) {
        super(data, heading);
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int cols) {
        if (getValueAt(0, cols) != null && cols > 0) {
            return getValueAt(0, cols).getClass();
        } else {
            return String.class;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: You don't show where you create the "fileVector", so I would guess that code is incorrect.

Comment: if i recall correctly you must a use a vector of Objects. Please refer to the javadoc documentaion on tables. Is quite long, but it will help you Thiruanvukkarasu! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: am also tried that one. but it throws a same exception. The same type of code can accepted in other project.

Comment: What type of `Vector` is your `fileVector?` Looking at the other constructors, a `DefaultTableModel` has a constructor of `(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames)`. Saying that, (guessing)  the `fileVector` would need to be a `Vector<Vector<Object>>`, right?
*EDIT*: Looking into the Source Code, it has a `convertToVector` method, which converts an `Object[][]` into a `Vector<Vector>`.

Comment: In addition to describing how you declare fileVector, please also describe how and where you create Table1. If you could supply a complete, self-contained Java program that demonstrates this problem, this problem could be solved within minutes.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception, you must added String object to fileVector, like this:

```
Vector fileVector = new Vector();
fileVector.add("a string object");
```

This is against the implementation of DefaultTableModel, to use it you need to add Vector object into fileVector, like this:

```
Vector fileVector = new Vector();
fileVector.add(new Vector(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"row1 col1", "row1 col2"})));
fileVector.add(new Vector(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"row2 col1", "row2 col2"})));
```

Cheers